# Deploying Angular app to NodeJS using Azure Devops

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-devops

Is there a way to automate deployment of Angular application to NodeJS or onPrem WebServer using Azure Devops PipeLines.

Comment: How do you deploy Angular application to NodeJS or onPrem WebServer locally? Do you meet any issue when use DevOps to do the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

For Angular apps, you can include Angular-specific commands such as **ng test**, **ng build**, and **ng e2e**. To use Angular CLI commands in your pipeline, you need to install the [angular/cli npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) on the build agent.

```
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
```

Note:

> On Microsoft-hosted Linux agents, preface the command with `sudo`,
>   like `sudo npm install -g`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#angular

Comment: Thanks for providing that helpfull information. Couple of queries
1) The Angular/cli npm package needs to be installed only once on the build agent or it needs to be one of the steps in the build pipeline for installing it whenever the build runs.
2) What template needs to be selected in the build and release pipeline for deploying the Angular app on a webserver and on a NodeJS server

Comment: 1) If you use Microsoft-hosted agent or new installed self-hosted agent, then you need to install Angular/cli npm package in the pipeline. 2) It depends on how you want to deploy the app. If you deploy the app from command line/Script, then you can add command line/script task to do the deployment.